# Z1 = 1, Z2 = 36, Z3, Z4 = 38346, Z5 = 1246285 … Zn, find Z3 and Zn?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

$Z_1 = 1, Z_2 = 36, Z_3=?, Z_4 = 38346, Z_5 = 1246285, ...$, find $Z_3$ and $Z_n$?

For info I have already $Z_n$; I just want to compare the results.

And if you want more value from this series I can provide it.

Here are more details about $Z_n$:

$Z_n$ increases exponentially at a certain level and then decreases towards $0$.

$Z_n$ is the whole part of a function of $n$.

Here are more values ​​of $Z_n$:

$Z_0$=0

$Z6 = 40504909,$
$Z7 = 1316424317,$
$Z8 = 42784149984.$

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

Here are some things I've noticed which might lead somebody else to the answer

> $$\frac{Z_2}{Z_1} \approx 36\,\,\,,\,\,\,\frac{Z_4}{Z_2} \approx (32.637)^2\,\,\,,\,\,\, \frac{Z_5}{Z_4} \approx 32.501$$
>  That is to say, it looks as though the sequence grows roughly exponentially.
>  The diminishing common ratio indicates to me that we might be looking at a recursive relationship which looks something like the following $$Z_{n+1} = \alpha Z_n + \beta_n $$ or perhaps the nearest integer to this quantity. I haven't yet been able to get an exact form for the $\beta_n$ but if we assume that the sequence is increasing, always and integer or half an integer and $\alpha = 32.5$ (which seems to be in the right ballpark) then we get the following sequence for $\beta_n$: $$3.5, 9, 28.5, 40,\ldots $$ That is to say $$36 = 32.5 \times 1 + 3.5\,\,\,,\,\,\, 1179 = 32.5 \times 36 + 9 \,\,\,,\,\,\, 38346 = 32.5 \times 1179 + 28.5$$ $$1246285 = 32.5 \times 38346 + 40 $$ This makes me think $Z_3 = 1179$ and that $Z_n$ grows roughly exponentially (but without an exact formula).

Comment: Thanks for your response, and well done for finding Z3. >! It is true that Zn increases exponentially at a certain level but then decreases towards 0. >! Zn is a function according to n and we just take the whole part lol